# Understand transactions to multiple domains resolving to the same wallet address

Tags: ethereum

If there are multiple domains resolving to the same wallet address, by watching the transactions of that wallet would it be possible to differentiate the transactions towards a domain or another?

**Example:**

My address `0x516F381d6C94110CDE63F3266B779065525096e6` resolves to `primary.eth`. `0x516F381d6C94110CDE63F3266B779065525096e6` (same address) also resolves `secondary.eth` and `tertiary.eth`.

If a user sends some ETH to `secondary.eth`, the ETH will reach `0x516F381d6C94110CDE63F3266B779065525096e6`.

By monitor the transactions occurred on `0x516F381d6C94110CDE63F3266B779065525096e6` is it possible to know that this user has sent the ETH to `secondary.eth`, instead of `primary.eth` or `tertiary.eth`?